# What is the purpose of the less.js and styles.less

Tags: less

Can someone explain why I would want to use the less.js script along with its stylesheet?  I don;t understand the purpose and its advantages.  Thank you. Erik

Comment: Check this article out, it should help - http://designshack.net/articles/css/using-less-js-to-simplify-your-css3/

Answer (score 8):

**Less.js** is a CSS pre-processor, it means that you will be able to write your in style using the Less pre-processor languages in a `*.less` file, then Less.js will compile it into pure CSS.

CSS pre-processor comes with a lot of powerful features such as: *variables*, *mixins*, *nested rules*, *operations*, *imports* and a [lot more](http://lesscss.org/).

With Less.js you have two options:

1. Running Less at **client-side**: write your styles in Less then include the JavaScript pre-processor: `Less.js`.
2. Running Less at **server-side**: write your styles in Less then run the pre-processor using Node.js or Rhino, and in other cases you may use some ports like [DotLess](http://www.dotlesscss.org/).

If you have potentially large Web Interface Design (complex layout, sprites, multiple navigation, several forms, etc...) then you *should* consider using one of the popular CSS pre-processor like [Less.js](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com). *They will help you a lot*.

**Keep in mind...** there are big project build on top of CSS pre-processor, [Twitter Bootsrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) use Less and [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) is a great framework that will kill your aches related to cross-browser issues concerning *inline-blocks*, *clearfix*, *box-shadow*, etc...