# How can I call a Less.js Function within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, less

How can I use a less.js function within JavaScript?

I want to use the mix function, [found here](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-mix), within normal JavaScript, so:

```
$('.orange-text').css({
    color: less.mix('#FF6B3A','#6600CC','50%')                       
});
```

But it is just always undefined, and I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to reference the function but surely its possible?

Comment: Is this the only function you want to use (mixing 2 colors)? Or do you want access to *every* less function?

Comment: Mixing the two colours based on a percentage

Comment: so the `50%` would mean half way between the two colors?

Comment: Yes and i want to be able to pass any percentage in and get the corresponding color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "official" way, but you can get function using `functionRegistry`.

Assuming you have `less.js` included on the page

```
var mix = less.functions.functionRegistry.get('mix');

var Color = less.tree.Color;
var d50 = new less.tree.Dimension(50);

var c1 = new Color("000fff");
var c2 = new Color("ff0000");
console.log(mix(c1, c2, d50).toRGB());
```

Note, that it uses `lessjs` internals and totally not reliable when migrating to other `less` version. So if you want only use one `mix` function, consider to find some library, or write your own mixing function.

30sec of googling: https://gist.github.com/jedfoster/7939513

Answer (score 3):

You can write a similar method using native javascript, the idea is pretty simple

1. Split each hex color into its component RGB, and convert to integers
2. for each of R,G & B interpolate between the two colours the amount determined by `weight` (the third parameter)
3. Convert each of the 3 new integers back to hex

Example below which matches the [less documentation example](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-mix)

```js
function HexToRgb(hexstr){
    var a = [];
  hexstr = hexstr.replace(/[^0-9a-f]+/ig, '');
    if (hexstr.length == 3) {
        a = hexstr.split('');
    } else if (hexstr.length == 6) {
        a = hexstr.match(/(\w{2})/g);
    }   
    else{
        throw "invalid input, hex string must be in the format #FFFFFF or #FFF"
    }
    return a.map(function(x) { return parseInt(x,16) });
}

function IntToHex(i){
    var hex = i.toString(16);
    if(hex.length == 1)
        hex = '0' + hex;
    return hex;
}

function Mix(colorA,colorB,weight){
   var a = HexToRgb(colorA);   
   var b = HexToRgb(colorB);
  
   var c0 = Math.round((a[0] + (Math.abs(a[0]-b[0])*weight)) % 255);
    var c1 = Math.round((a[1] + (Math.abs(a[1]-b[1])*weight)) % 255);
    var c2 = Math.round((a[2] + (Math.abs(a[2]-b[2])*weight)) % 255);
   
    return "#" + IntToHex(c0) + IntToHex(c1) + IntToHex(c2)
}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = Mix("#ff0000","#0000ff",0.5);
```

```html
Mixing #ff0000 and #0000ff at 50% gives <span id="output"><span>
```

Answer (score 1):

It cant be used in that way. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655171/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-less-js-and-styles-less). less.js is a client side pre-processor which turns your less style to css.

Comment: Is there any way to mimic the functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a helper function named `lessToCSS` into the `document` , and you can call it, anytime you want to use some less to style something in your application.

Example:

```js
(function(d) {
  d.lessToCSS = function (css) {
    less.render(css).then(function(obj) {
      var stl = d.createElement('style');
      stl.textContent = obj.css;
      d.querySelector('head').appendChild(stl);
    });
  };
})(document);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  document.lessToCSS('.orange-text { background-color: mix(#FF6B3A, #6600CC, 50%) }');
});
```

```css
.orange-text {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.1/less.min.js"></script>
<div class="orange-text">
  Test
</div>
<button>Change background</button>
```

Comment: The advangage of this answer is that you can use any CSS you would include in a `.less` file and less will render for you. You don't need to get the function, and then call it, nor use the less trees etc.